# Why can't I start a bounty?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I would like to start a bounty for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213750/8323). Am I missing the obvious?

Why can't I start a bounty?

## Screens

See by yourself:

[image]

as opposed to

[image]

## What happen if I click on "bounty is available"

[image]

Comment: It says it's eligible for a bounty, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Where can I start it?

Comment: I guess it is because I don't have enough points! Maybe this should be said somewhere!

Comment: You only need 75 rep to start a bounty.

Comment: Yes but I think I already started bounties for this question.

Comment: What happens when you click on "question has been eligible for bounty since..."?

Comment: @Werner See edit

Comment: FAQ reference: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/168244)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not have enough reputation to add another bounty. You added a [250 rep bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/213750/revisions) on December 5th. For you to add another one, you must [double the reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639). You do not have 500 reputation to offer such a bounty.

Comment: However, this should bring a warning. I'm tempted to consider this a boundary bug/feature-request.